# How can I create a custom template for category and add the job filter in it, in WP JOB MANAGER plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

How can I create a custom template for job categories in WP Job Manager instead of using the default WordPress archive template? I would like to have a separate template for each individual job category.

Additionally, I want to add a job search filter to each single category page. The search should only search for jobs within the specific category when the user is on that particular category page. For example, if the category is “WordPress,” I want users to be able to search for jobs only within the WordPress category.

WP JOB MANAGER plugin

The page I need help with: http://zeroguess.us/n03/selear/job-category/caltech/

Currently, I tried to echo the jobs shortcode, but it searches through all the categories, and I can’t dynamically specify the category parameter.https://prnt.sc/1ddjPaBVeJgo